# Change json values

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, freshdesk

Is it possible to change the value in a json file.

Little bit of background ground I'm able to pull ticket data from Freshdesk using their api. The status of the ticket comes down as a number. So for example a "open" ticket would have a value of 2. I want it to actually say open instead of two. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving it as a file you could just do a find and replace

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\file.json).replace('status: 1', 'status: \'Open\'') | Set-Content c:\temp\file.json
```

and repeat for the different possible values of status

Or

```
$a = Get-Content 'D:\temp\file.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$a.update | % {if($_.status -eq 1){$_.status='Open'}}
$a | ConvertTo-Json  | set-content 'D:\temp\file.json'
```

and repeat line 2 for each value of status

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a map and check it against it every time.
For example

```js
const getType = t => ({ 
    2: "Open",
    3: "Pending",
    4: "Resolved",
    5: "Closed"
  })[t]
;
```

Comment: @bluuf My bad, the question didn't have any mention Powershell in and I assumed it's JS related since Freshdek platform provides a node.js env